# Force ServerXMLHTTP to use existing windows socket to connect to internet?

Tags: vb6, network-programming, winsock, serverxmlhttp

Is that possible to force the ServerXMLHTTP to connect to internet through an existing  windows socket?

For some reasons, I'm using VB6 winsock control and the winsock connected to a certain PC. I want to communicate with that PC in SSL protocol, but I need to implement too much thing to make winsock work properly like ServerXMLHTTP.

So, yes or no, can I force the ServerXMLHTTP (or event WinInet) to work using existing windows socket?

Comment: Are you wanting to just SSL encrypt a plain vanilla TCP connection between two computers or do you want to make an SSL encrypted HTTP connection (HTTPS) between two computers?

Comment: @NormanH: I want to secure a TCP connection only, but with VB6, it's really hard even with openSSL. (As I know, no one has combined VB6 & OpenSSL before). So, I'm gonna make a PC to be webserver & the other to be client. And ServerXMLHTTP was the first thing I thought about.. but, wait, I need to connect exactly via an existing winSock!

Comment: Did a little searching, it looks like what you are trying to accomplish is quite difficult at best if you roll your own.  See this thread for details.  http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=295328

Comment: You have already setup an existing connection and just wish to have it SSL encrypted some of the time?   If all you want to do is encrypt your communication, why don't you use a simple shared key cipher and encrypt just the communications that you want secure?  That might be the easiest way to go while retaining your need to have a single socket connection reused.  There aren't standard protocols that I am aware of that would support that operation however.

Comment: @NormanH I have AES128 & RC4 here, but I want to implement the full feature of SSL protocol,  cause I need confidence in my connection. I've search every single article that "smells" SSL, but found nothing. I'm willing to give any one 500 reputation on Stackoverflow to help me achieve this.

Comment: Lots of reading ahead in this SSL v3 draft specification document. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-ssl-version3-00  Do you know what version of the SSL protocol you wish to support and which ciphers you are able/willing to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options for implementing the SSL protocol with access through VB6/COM interfaces.

- Expose COM interfaces around .NET Framework custom code and [libraries for encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then call your .NET created COM interfaces from your VB6 application.
- Utilize an [off-the-shelf component](http://www.dart.com/ssl-activex-library-api.aspx) that already has the SSL protocol implemented for you.
- Implement the [full SSL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ssl-version3-00) in VB6

After clarification about the need to use an "existing windows socket" I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: I'm trying to implement SSL V3.0 or higher with RSA_WITH_AES128_AND_SHA512 (CipheSpec = 0x2f). Regarding your answer: 1/I know that the encrypting function are out there, in .Net or CryptoAPI, but I have them already enough in VB6. The point is, I need to combine all them in a comlicated system with tons of syntaxes, structure, blah blah blah... 2/ All the commercial activeX components out there are insanely expensive. 3/ Must I read all that long RFC and follow the even longer related documents? It takes dozen years. I need a shortcut, that's the goal of this question. Thanks.